# The man with a wooden jaw

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Cached in secrecy,
Where none shall interfere
A man with wooden jaw
Waits patiently each year

Hands flung abroad,
As the masked man cries "unscathed!"
In an abode of luxury,
With reservations made

Combatants from a land
Found on distant shores
With an intruder well acquainted
With the sound of people's snores

A shape at the heart
Of an ages-old tale
Followed by what's great and blue,
But isn't a whale

What is it?

Hint 1:

> Verses 1 and 2 are two ways of describing the same thing, and involve a bit of puns/wordplay. Verses 3 and 4 go together and describe something else, which is a clue to arriving at the correct answer.

Hint 2:

> The ages-old tale referred to in the last verse happened about 2000 years ago, give or take 33 years. The "combatants from a land found on distant shores" were active about 40 years ago.

Hint 3:

> The masked man is one of a couple masked men that show up in another common riddle, although surprisingly I couldn't find any version of that riddle on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> SAFE-CRACKER

*Cached in secrecy, 

 Where none shall interfere*

> This is a good description of **safe**ness.

*A man with wooden jaw 

 Waits patiently each year*

As [Nathan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/10225/5373) already realised, these lines refer to

> a nut**cracker**.

*Hands flung abroad,

As the masked man cries "unscathed!"*

The OP's 3rd hint tells us that this is

> a **baseball** reference.

Thanks to [bubalou](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10218/the-man-with-a-wooden-jaw-riddle/10369?noredirect=1#comment32052_10369) for telling me that more specifically,

> it's a reference to an umpire calling a runner **safe**.

*In an abode of luxury,

 With reservations made*

> I think this is a Christmas **cracker**.

The OP's first hint tells us that verses 1 and 2 are two ways of describing the same thing. That thing is

> a safe-cracker.

*Combatants from a land

 Found on distant shores*

> This is a reference to the nickname **Charlie** for Viet Cong fighters (thanks to [Duncan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10218/the-man-with-a-wooden-jaw-riddle/10369?noredirect=1#comment32040_10369) for putting me onto the reason for this).

*With an intruder well acquainted

 With the sound of people's snores*

> This is Z, as in "zzz" snoring. The OP is American, so it's "**zee**" rather than "zed".

*A shape at the heart

 Of an ages-old tale*

> The letter **T** (as in the Christian cross).

*Followed by what's great and blue,

 But isn't a whale*

> A [**heron**](http://animals.nationalgeographic.com/animals/birds/great-blue-heron/).

So the final two verses give

> [Charlize Theron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlize_Theron), who played a safe-cracker in the 2003 film [*The Italian Job*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Italian_Job_(2003_film)). Confirmation!

Comment: You got some parts right! The intruder is the letter z, and you're on the right track with the shape but if it's not the letter x which letter could it be?

Comment: @Ben I've made some edits re the last verse.

Comment: T is right! Great blue may take some looking up, if you aren't already familiar with what it's referring to.

Comment: @Ben What sort of looking up? Googling "great blue" didn't bring any luck. Also, have I got the right idea with "abode" or is that bit way off?

Comment: Abode is way off, unfortunately. Great blue refers to an animal other than a whale, and when you put it together with T you get a name...

Comment: @Ben Is [Theron](http://animals.nationalgeographic.com/animals/birds/great-blue-heron/) a name?

Comment: Yep! :) And the verse before goes along with it

Comment: @Ben New edit made!

Comment: Charlize Theron is right! The first 2 verses refer not exactly to her profession, but to one of the roles she is better "Known For" (that's a hint too, I'm not sure if it's the most helpful though).

Comment: I've also added a new hint regarding the second verse

Comment: "Charlie" is a slang term for Viet Cong guerilla fighters during Vietnam. It comes from "Victor Charlie" the NATO phonetic alphabet used for "VC".

Comment: I believe the baseball reference is an umpire calling a runner "safe"

Comment: @bubalou Bingo! And "safe" is half of the final answer

Comment: @Ben Anything to do with [this film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Italian_Job_(2003_film))? Edit: I think I've solved it! That was a nice, but hard, riddle - I don't think I could have done it without your hints and confirmations.

Comment: @rand al'thor Safe cracker it is! Haha yeah I'm still learning how to write riddles that are clever, challenging, and yet still solvable. The only last part is the abode of luxury, which I knew would be a stretch. Basically "abode... with reservations made" -> a hotel, "luxury" -> the Ritz hotel -> Ritz cracker

Comment: @Ben If I can add a note, try not to write riddles containing references to a specific country or culture, e.g. the baseball reference or _zee_ and slightly the Viet Cong nickname. I as italian could never ever get those parts, even with a clear and plain hint. _Combatants from a land Found on distant shores_ can refer to pratically any sea war. This, of course, if you want a broad audience.

Answer (score 5):

The solution:

> The horse of Troy or [Trojan Horse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_Horse)

Cached in secrecy,
Where none shall interfere
A man with wooden jaw
Waits patiently each year

> The horse. It can be thought as a man with *wooden jaw*, containing the greeks in his mouth (belly). No clue on the last sentence, maybe because each year its taught to a different generation so "waits"?

Hands flung abroad,
As the masked man cries "unscathed!"
In an abode of luxury,
With reservations made

> Hands of greeks over Troy. The others sentences can be explained, but are a bit stretched (luxury of greeks, golden [mask of Agamemnon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_of_Agamemnon), the greeks pretend to return home after 10 years to be "unscathed"...)

Combatants from a land
Found on distant shores
With an intruder well acquainted
With the sound of people's snores

> This is self explanatory. Combatants (the greeks) from a land found on distant shores (Greece) with an intruder well acquainted (the horse) with the sound of people's snores (the greeks attacked Troy during the night, when everyone was sleeping)

A shape at the heart
Of an ages-old tale
Followed by what's great and blue,
But isn't a whale

> The tale is the [Aeneid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeneid), followed by the [Odyssey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odyssey), where, after the concquer of Troy, Ulisses has to cross the *great and blue sea* to return home.

What is it?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm. Not sure about this, and missing some of the clues, but...

> A nutcracker - specifically, the decorative soldier type.

Cached in secrecy,
Where none shall interfere
A man with wooden jaw
Waits patiently each year

> Stored every year in an out-of-the-way cupboard, until Christmas rolls around. (I would think the typical soldier nutcracker is just used as decoration.)

Hands flung abroad,
As the masked man cries "unscathed!"
In an abode of luxury,
With reservations made

> Not a clue.

Combatants from a land
Found on distant shores

> The soldier nutcracker originated in Germany, and typically wears a dress uniform of that area from an ancient period. If you're not on the European mainland, you could consider Germany to be "distant shores".

With an intruder well acquainted
With the sound of people's snores

> Santa Claus is also associated with Christmas. In legend, he sneaks down people's chimneys while they are asleep to leave them presents.

A shape at the heart
Of an ages-old tale

> A soldier nutcracker is a eponymous player in The Nutcracker by Tchaikovsky, a popular ballet first performed in 1892. That ballet in turn was based on an even older tale written in 1816 by E. T. A. Hoffman.

Followed by what's great and blue,
But isn't a whale

> If a rambunctious child accidentally whacks you with a hard wooden nutcracker, you may wish to replace it with a large and soft blue teddy bear....Joking. :) Not a clue here either.

Comment: You're on the right track! A nutcracker is indeed what I am referring to in lines 3 and 4